# Selecting last message from conversation

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to make a facebook style private message.

I have four tables, user, conversation, conversation reply, and conversation_user.

A conversation can be more than 2 participants, conversation_user is used as the pivot table.

Conversation reply table has user_id and conversation id.

How do I select the last 5 conversation by conversation and show the last message of the conversation?

Is there a better database schema that I am missing?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6908b2

Comment: Cross-posted on [dba.se]: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134239/selecting-last-message-from-conversation

Answer (score 0):

First you should add a Date to the conversation then select with limit 5, body from conversations_reply where the user id equals to the one you want.

```
SELECT Body FROM conversations_reply
WHERE user_id = @user_id
ORDER BY Converstaion_Date
LIMIT 5;
```